# Mapbox Editor Marker Not Showing on Android

Tags: android, layer, mapbox

I tried using the Mapbox editor to create a map and show it in a simple native Android App. I can show the map I created. I can change the style of the map, and the change shows.

However, when I add a polygon or Marker to my online map, it doesn't show up on my Android app's map.

Should it?

Answer (score 0):

From the folks at Mapbox... "Unfortunately, the Android SDK doesn't fully implement all of the features that our platform offers. Markers, polygons, and such have to be done in code."